# Exporting a plugin from Eclipse: JDTCompilerAdapter not found

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, pde

I'm trying to update an old eclipse plugin to work on the more recent version of Eclipse. Everything compiles fine, but when I try to export the plugin, I get the following error:

```
Class not found: org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter
```

Any clue as to what I might be doing wrong?

(For the record, I'm running Eclipse Indigo under OS X Snow Leopard.)

Comment: Isn't there some kind of stack trace associated with the error? Check your Error log view or the log files created in the export directory.

Comment: There was no stack trace - however, when I checked the "Use class files compiled in the workspace" checkbox, the problem went away.

Comment: Well, that **did** work, until I tried to build the update site.xml and then got the same problem. It's a modal dialog with a "Details >>" button, but the details view doesn't show a complete stack trace. There's no console. The message reads:

The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/talin/Projects/tart-eclipse/org.viridia.tart.eclipse/build.xml:207: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/talin/Projects/tart-eclipse/org.viridia.tart.eclipse/build.xml:168: Class not found: org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter